# JBPM6 process definition versioning

Tags: java, jboss, versioning, jbpm, bpmn

We have process definition deployed in production and lots of process instances are initialized and in flight.

Now there are changes required to be done in process definition (.bpmn file) to accommodate other business scenarios.

We understand that we can not just replace the old .bpmn file with new one because old .bpmn file may be referred by in flight processes.

**What is easiest and best way to handle this situation?**

Note: We are using JBPM 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new version:

1. Make your edits to the process definition and anything else in the project.
2. Make sure the project and process definition is saved.
3. In the Project editor->Project General Settings change the version number.
4. Save, build and deploy.
5. A new version is deployed.  The deployment id will have the new version number:

   GenusOU:MCTestWF1:2.0

In the repository there will be a separate version directory for each version in the project.
The project's maven-metadata.xml will contain all versions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>GenusOU</groupId>
  <artifactId>MCTestWF1</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>3.0</release>
    <versions>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20160825183701</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Comment: All new process instances will use the new, release, version.  Existing process instances will continue using the old bpmn2 file.  That is, the bpmn2 file associated with the version in the process instance's deployment-id.